# How do I rerender mathquill.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mathquill

The problem is, I'm using angularjs ng-include to load partial, and mathquill box is in the partial, if I put

```
<script src="/MathQuill/mathquill.js"></script>
```

in the partial view, it works fine, but I will get a warning:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its   detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

If I put

```
<script src="/MathQuill/mathquill.js"></script>
```

in the main view, after loading partial, mathquill doesn't work at all, so is this the rendering problem? How do I re-render the partial view? Or if it's not, how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in mathquill website:

Note that for dynamically created elements that weren't in the HTML DOM on document ready, you will need to call our jQuery plugin after inserting into the visible HTML DOM:

```
$('<span>x^2</span>').appendTo('body').mathquill() or .mathquill('editable')
```